# Reshaping a numpy array to a lower triangular matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I want to reshape an arbitrary 1-d Numpy array, call it `a`, into a specific lower triangular matrix, call it `m`. The following example illustrates the transformation.

Start with a 1-d array, `a`

```
array([ 3,  2,  9, 12])
```

and create the following lower triangular matrix, `m`

```
array([[ 3,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  3,  0,  0],
       [ 9,  2,  3,  0],
       [12,  9,  2,  3]])
```

Comment: There is a set of `np.tri...` functions.  One or more can be used to create such an array, but it's likely to need a 10 element array, not just 4.  In other words, the kind of repetition that you want is not automatic.

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj. I tried a number of those, in conjunction with transposing and rotations, with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `scipy` available then there is `scipy.linalg.toeplitz`:

```
from scipy import linalg

linalg.toeplitz([3,2,9,12],[0,0,0,0])
# array([[ 3,  0,  0,  0],
#        [ 2,  3,  0,  0],
#        [ 9,  2,  3,  0],
#        [12,  9,  2,  3]])
```

Comment: Thank you @loopy wait! (That's what I get for forgetting my econometrics course.)